# Saving pyplots to a list in a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I would like to make an animation of the following plot such that it draws from left to right.

```
x = np.arange(1,10,1)
y = x * 2 - 1 + np.random.normal(0,1,9)
z = y / x
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y, 'z':z})
df.set_index('x', drop=True, inplace=True)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
ax1.plot(df['y'], color='darkred')
ax2.bar(x=df.index, height=df['z'])
ax1.margins(0)
ax2.margins(0)
```

I am seeking a generic solution such that I can create either 1) a plot function taking data as input or 2) a class which have a plot function and pass either 1 or 2 to my LcAnimation class. An example of a plot with a single subplot is given beneath.
How do I best pass a plot function to my LcAnimation class (the code beneath do work for a simple plot, but not with multiple subplots).

```
import matplotlib.animation as anim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class LcAnimation:
    def __init__(self, data, fig):
        '''
        :param data: A data frame containing the desired data for plotting
        :param fig: A matplotlib.pyplot figure on which the plot is drawn
        '''
        self.data = data.copy()
        self.fig = fig
        self.plots = []

    def create_animation(self, plot_class):
        '''
        :return: A list with the animated plots
        '''
        for i in range(0, len(self.data)):
            data_temp = self.data.loc[:i, ].copy()
            plt_im = plot_class.plot(data_temp)
            self.plots.append(plt_im)

    def save_animation(self, filename, fps = 10):
        '''

        :param filename: Destination at which the animation should be saved
        :return: Saves the animation
        '''
        animation_art = anim.ArtistAnimation(self.fig, self.plots)
        animation_art.save(filename, writer='pillow', fps=fps)

class MyPlot:

    def plot(self, data):
        plt_im = plt.plot(data['x'], data['y'], color='darkred')
        return plt_im


x = np.arange(1,10,1)
y = x * 2 - 1 + np.random.normal(0,1,9)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})

fig = plt.figure()

# Test the module
my_plot = MyPlot()
MyFirstAnimation = LcAnimation(df, fig)
MyFirstAnimation.create_animation(my_plot)
MyFirstAnimation.save_animation('path', fps=5)
```

An example of how I would like the animation to work for multiple subplots and not just 1:
[Animation of y for each x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0kzi.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing anything in the LcAnimation class you can just use `ax1` and `ax2` in the plotting function.

```
x = np.arange(1,10,1)
y = x * 2 - 1 + np.random.normal(0,1,9)
z = y / x
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y, 'z':z})
df.set_index('x', drop=True, inplace=True)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
ax1.margins(0)
ax2.margins(0)

class MyPlot:

    def plot(self, data):
        line, = ax1.plot(data['y'], color='darkred')
        bars = ax2.bar(x=data.index, height=data['z'], color='darkred')
        return [line,*bars]

# Test the module
my_plot = MyPlot()
MyFirstAnimation = LcAnimation(df, fig)
MyFirstAnimation.create_animation(my_plot)
MyFirstAnimation.save_animation('path.gif', fps=5)
```

[image]

Comment: That is an excellent solution. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.